# Correct java.time representation of XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, java-time, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have a XML element with the following content:

```
<lastModified>2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00</lastModified>
```

This is mapped to Java's `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

I need to convert this value in an appropriate java.time instance.

I am a little confused about which java.time class is the "correct" (i.e. lossless) representation of this `XMLGregorianCalendar` value.

I suppose it should be `ZonedDateTime` or is `OffsetDateTime` the better choice?

Comment: It depends a lot. `ZonedDateTime` is an option, but since an `XMLGregorianCalendar` so-called *timezone* isn’t but a mere UTC offset, I’d tend more towards `OffsetDateTime`. However, any field in an `XMLGreforianCalendar` may be undefined, so depending on concrete use in some situation `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` or about any java.time date or time class may be appropriate.

Comment: Ok, it turns out you have to use an `OffsetDateTime` because your `String` `2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00` does not contain a zone but an offset (one that several zones might have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String` you have (`"2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00"`) is in an ISO format that doesn't even need an extra formatter in order to parse it. The main reason for the use of an `OffsetDateTime` are the last 6 characters: `+02:00`, which denote an offset of 2 hours from UTC (more than just one time zone may actually have this offset at the same time).

You can convert this value into **the** proper `java.time` instance like this, for example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    // your example datetime
    String lastModified = "2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00";
    // create an XMLGregorianCalendar for example purpose
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGC = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                                                .newXMLGregorianCalendar(lastModified);
    // print it once in order to see the values
    System.out.println("XMLGregorianCalendar: " + xmlGC.toString());
    // parse its toString() method to an OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime lastModOdt = OffsetDateTime.parse(xmlGC.toString());
    // format the content of the OffsetDateTime in ISO standard
    System.out.println("OffsetDateTime:       " 
            + lastModOdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
}
```

Output:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar: 2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00
OffsetDateTime:       2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00
```

This should be correct (lossless enough by losing no information).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to work with a XMLGregorianCalendar instance and not with a string representation.

Comment: @Abid OK, see my edit, you can basically parse the `toString()` method of an `XMLGregorianCalendar`…

Comment: Yes, there are many time zones that share offset +02:00 at this time. Just a few examples are Africa/Mbabane, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Madrid, Africa/Bujumbura, Antarctica/Troll, Arctic/Longyearbyen and Europe/Kaliningrad.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with a similar problem all morning and Ole's comments were more insightful than the accepted answer so thought I should post the conclusion I came to.

Technically yes, the exact equivalent to XMLGregorianCalendar is OffsetDateTime (assuming your example, where you have y-m-d h:m:s+z fields populated) as the time zone offset is known but which actual time zone it is is unknown (as per other comments, there are many time zones all with offset +2:00).  You can convert it easily like so, without going via an intermediary string:

```
xmlGC.toGregorianCalendar ().toZonedDateTime ().toOffsetDateTime ()
```

But I think the real answer is *it depends what you want to do with it*.  In my case, I want to display the date/time to the user.  If that is true, do you really care what time zone the date/time happened to be stored as in the XML?  The following are both effectively identical, i.e. they both represent the same point in time.

```
<lastModified>2019-10-09T19:20:45.677+02:00</lastModified>
<lastModified>2019-10-09T20:20:45.677+01:00</lastModified>
```

If you don't care about the time zone from the XML and just the point in time it reperesents, then the correct answer is Instant, which you can get like

```
xmlGC.toGregorianCalendar ().toInstant ()
```

and from there apply whatever time zone the user is in, rather than the time zone from the XML.  So for me the right answer was to do:

```
xmlGC.toGregorianCalendar ().toInstant ().atZone (ZoneId.systemDefault ())
```